# Python Close Shell with no popup

Tags: python

I am looking for way to exit the python shell without the Kill? popup

```
print ("Hello")
print ("Press any key to exit")
ex = raw_input ("")
exit
```

I am talking about the python shell for windows not the command prompt.

This is the popup I want to ignore and close the program after the user has hit any key.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add parenthesis after the exit() to call the exit function. As it is now, it is not executing it as a function.

The following will exit the script without showing a command prompt, but you will still need to exit IDLE on your own.

```
import os

print ("Hello")
print ("Press any key to exit")
ex = raw_input ("")
os._exit(0)
```

Comment: but this doesn't ignores python shell popup box.

Comment: Good point. Actually, try using os._exit() to terminate the CPython process immediately. That might stop the shell from thinking the script is still running.

Comment: `os_exit(0)` does nothing except restarting the shell(similar to ctrl+f6 on windows).

Comment: I updated the answer to use os._exit(0) instead, and that should do the trick.

Comment: Windows user in IDLE with python 3.9.2 here, "os._exit(0)" just restarts the shell; it does not close it. So so far, "exit()" is the closest I have gotten to closing the shell via script, but again, still want to get rid of the confirmation popup. No solution here that I can get working.